# integral of arctg

Tags: real-analysis

I have to determine 
$$
\int_{- \infty }^{\infty} \operatorname{arctg} x\, dx
$$
I know that 
$$
\int_{- \infty }^{\infty} \operatorname{arctg} x\, dx=
 [x\operatorname{arctg} x]_{-\infty }^{\infty}-
\frac{1}{2}[\log(1+x^2)]_{-\infty }^{\infty}
$$
but now I don't know how to go on.

(Note: $\operatorname{arctg}$ is the same as $\arctan$.)

Comment: What makes you think that this improper integral converges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (improper) integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\operatorname{arctg}x\,dx
$$
exists if and only if both
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}\operatorname{arctg}x\,dx
$$
and
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{-1}\operatorname{arctg}x\,dx
$$
exist and are finite.

However, for $x\ge1$ we have $\operatorname{arctg}x\ge\pi/4$, so, for $a>1$,
$$
\int_1^a\operatorname{arctg}x\,dx>\frac{\pi}{4}(a-1)
$$
and so
$$
\lim_{a\to\infty}
\int_{1}^{a}\operatorname{arctg}x\,dx=\infty
$$

Answer (score 1):

This integral diverges. First you have to consider only $\;\DeclareMathOperator\arctg{arctg}\displaystyle\int_0^\infty x\arctg x\,\mathrm dx$. Second $x\arctg x$ does not tend to $0$ at infinity.

Indeed $\arctg x\sim_\infty\dfrac\pi2$, so $x\arctg x\sim_\infty\dfrac{\pi x}2\to+\infty$.

Comment: so $\;\DeclareMathOperator\arctg{arctg}\displaystyle\int_0^\infty x\arctg x\,\mathrm dx$ is not determined, isn't it?

Comment: @Anne Draw a graphical representation : it makes it so evident !!!

Comment: No, it's not. The integrals of two equivalent functions both converge or both diverge.